# Token Comma Expected in Power Query Advanced Editor Error Message

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Would anyone please review the following code to see why I keep getting a "Token Comma Expected" error message in Power BI Advanced Editor M Code:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure let is lowercase (let and not Let).